# Cannot store Certificate to KeyChain using SecKeyChain in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, certificate, keychain

After hours spent reading through what's available online to fix this, I decided to post my question here.
My goal is simple: Store an X509Certficate to KeyChain using Xamarin for iOS. This is a self signed certificate that I generated using BouncyCastle library.
I'm successfuly importing it, but when saving to KeyChain using `SecKeyChain.Add`, the result is always `SecStatusCode.Param`which the documentation explains is missing or invalid parameter. Here's the method I use

```
public static bool StoreCertInKeyChain(X509Certificate2 certificate, string password)
{
    var data = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, password);

    var options = NSMutableDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(FromObject(password), SecImportExport.Passphrase);

    var statusCode = SecImportExport.ImportPkcs12(data, options, out NSDictionary[] result);
    if (statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success) return false;

    var certChain = result[0][SecImportExport.CertChain];
    var record = new SecRecord(SecKind.Certificate)
    {
        Label = "MyKey",
        Account = "Certificate",
        ApplicationTag = "MyTag"
    };
    record.SetValueRef(certChain);

    // Using the below code instead, produces the same result
    // var cert = new SecCertificate(certChain.Handle);
    // record.SetValueRef(cert);

    var resultAdd = SecKeyChain.Add(record);
    return resultAdd == SecStatusCode.Success;
}
```

Has anyone ran into this problem? I'm out of ideas what else to try. I followed the examples given on Xamarin documentation site, without success. Thank you

Comment: Did you enable keychain in `Entitlements.plist`?

Comment: I did, that wasn't the problem. Added an answer with some code that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my solution here, in case anyone else runs into the same issue. The problem was that the certificate supplied in the `SecRecord` wasn't an instance of `SecCertificate`, so using `SecImportExport.ImportPkcs12` was the wrong way to do it. I ended up using `SecIdentity.Import` instead, which gives a reference to the certificate as well as the private key in it. The certificate and the private key need to be added to key chain separately using an identity. Here's the code that accomplishes this.

```
    var identity = SecIdentity.Import(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, password), password);
    var storedCertificate = SecKeyChain.QueryAsConcreteType(new SecRecord(SecKind.Certificate) { Label = "My Cert" }, out SecStatusCode statusCode);
    if (statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success)
    {
        var record = new SecRecord(SecKind.Certificate);
        record.Label = "My Cert";
        record.SetValueRef(identity.Certificate);
        var result = SecKeyChain.Add(record);

        SecKeyChain.AddIdentity(identity);

        storedCertificate = SecKeyChain.QueryAsConcreteType(new SecRecord(SecKind.Certificate) { Label = "My Cert" }, out statusCode);
    }
    var storedIdentity = SecKeyChain.FindIdentity(storedCertificate as SecCertificate);
```

The certificate can be retrieved using the label, but to get the private key, the identity must be queried using the certificate as parameter in `SecKeyChain.FindIdentity`. From this point on, access to signing and decryption on the private key is available from the identity instance.